# Pandas fetching data between two time range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the below dataframe df1 I need to get all the datas between the opening and closing time from df2

Eg: Consider 3rd row of df1, in df2 i have the data between the opening and closing time of df which I need to join to df1

df1

| closingTime | openingTime | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 11:20:00 | 2022-01-31 10:41:00 | David |
| 2022-04-07 13:49:00 | 2022-04-07 09:56:00 | Alex |
| 2021-11-25 13:49:00 | 2021-11-25 13:46:00 | Hannah |
| 2021-11-16 10:20:00 | 2021-11-16 10:18:00 | Nan |
| 2022-01-03 11:08:00 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | John |

df2:

| time | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-25 13:46:00 | 1.12 |
| 2021-11-25 13:47:00 | 1.10 |
| 2021-11-25 13:48:00 | 1.16 |
| 2021-11-25 13:49:00 | 1.11 |
| 2021-11-25 13:50:00 | 1.21 |
| 2021-11-25 13:51:00 | 0.9 |
| 2021-11-25 13:52:00 | 1.17 |

Is there anyways to join the df to get the values between two time intervals?

Comment: What is the size of `df1` and `df2` in your real case?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! They'll be of different sizes actually

Comment: But what is the output `len(df1)` and `len(df2)`?

Comment: df1 len is 4k+ and df2 is more than 100k

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cross product of your 2 dataframes:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='cross').query('(openingTime<=time) & (time<=closingTime)')

            closingTime          openingTime    Name                 time  Price
14  2021-11-25 13:49:00  2021-11-25 13:46:00  Hannah  2021-11-25 13:46:00   1.12
15  2021-11-25 13:49:00  2021-11-25 13:46:00  Hannah  2021-11-25 13:47:00   1.10
16  2021-11-25 13:49:00  2021-11-25 13:46:00  Hannah  2021-11-25 13:48:00   1.16
17  2021-11-25 13:49:00  2021-11-25 13:46:00  Hannah  2021-11-25 13:49:00   1.11
```